# adding a value to 'datetime' column caused an overflow sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

===================================

Error at DTSTask_DTSDataPumpTask_1 [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
 Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.".

Error at DTSTask_DTSDataPumpTask_1 [OLE DB Source [1]]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source.
 Make sure your target table in the database is available.

(Microsoft Visual Studio)

Comment: You will receive more responses if you edit your question so as to provide all relevant information.  If you need help doing so, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no way you can get help without providing relevant information. These message is generic and one would have to guess how your job design look like in order to offer any help. I suggest you really spend some time and provide more information if you really need help. Which packages are you using? How does your dataflow look like? Which SQL query is the one causing the issue? How does your table structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Source has datetime column but destination has no such column. So, please check your source and destination connection, table, select/insert query.